# Add text-transform: none and font-weight :bold styles to <md-buttons> in angular materials design without inline css

Tags: angular-material

I am working on a project that is using angular materials design and I wanted to add certain styles to  without using inline css but could not figure out the best way to do same.

Please note I tried adding a class with those styles but it was by default picking styles from .md-button class and was not picking the Css class I added

CSS class

```
.button__style {
  text-transform :none;
  font-weight :bold;
 }
```

HTML

```
<md-button class='button__style'>Click me </md-button>
```

Also I know we can manipulate the default theme colors as below but wanted to find out if I am missing a way to add the two styles I require above i.e. text-transform : none and font-weight :bold;

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
 .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
   .primaryPalette('pink')
   .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML

```
<div class='button__style'>
<md-button >Click me </md-button>
</div>
```

In your CSS :

```
.button__style {
    button {
        text-transform: none;
        font-weight :bold;
//or any style you want to apply
        }
}
```

Try this.

[Code pen example for your problem](http://codepen.io/snehav27/pen/BNdXpe)

Comment: Thanks this helps but I was wondering if we can do theming like we do with colors.

Comment: I am not sure on how it works using theming . It would be great to know if anybody has the answer.